# Discord app won't open through Brave browser. xdg-open

Tags: 22.04, dpkg, snap, xdg-open, brave

Whenever I want to join a new server I receive the pop-up for Open-xdg-open but this does nothing. This is only happening in Brave browser for Discord specifically, other apps and browsers are working just fine.

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, snap of Discord 0.0.28 and native dpkg of Brave Browser 115.1.56.11.